# How are multiple Wordpress WPDB queries handled?

Tags: mysql

In my code, I use this query to get all the rows where credited field is false:

```
$uncredited_incentives_query = $wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT * FROM $incentives_table WHERE user_id = %s AND credited = FALSE ",
    $sponsor->ID
);
```

Then I work with the results. Then I have to set the credited field as true for the rows which were returned by the previous query. I am currently using this aproach.

```
$wpdb->update(
$incentives_table,
array(
    'credited' => true
),
array(
    'user_id'  => $sponsor->ID,
    'credited' => false
)
);
```

But I don't want to include any new rows which may have been added since this code was executed. So I want to know how is that possible? Am I using the correct approach?. If not, then how can I do so?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: You need to have a unique identifier for each row and in your loop to update where this unique identifier.Or to save all the unique identifiers in a array and then update all in 1 time instead of updating each row in the loop.

Comment: Do you mean something like this:
[link]https://stackoverflow.com/a/8873956/3659689
@Shibi

Comment: No I meant like you did but instead of using the `user_id` use a column thats unique to the row.

Comment: @Shibi I can do this using row ids. but the row ids array will be very large upto millions and more. I don;t think that will be wise to pass as an argument to [code]WHERE[/code]? Can you suggest any efficient method for doing that?

Comment: Maybe you can create some temp column that you update first with the user_id + timestamp for example and then select all the rows by this value. and update again by this value after you doing what you wanted. Or you can add some variable `$x = 0;` and increase it every row and every 100 rows to update.

Comment: Or you can use it as you did before but you need to add to the where the row_id <= last_row_id that you got.. I guess the row_id is auto increment so it will work fine

Comment: Can you please explain how can I implement the aproach by creating temp. column? My rowids may contain gaps. @shibi

Comment: Every new row the row_id is higher than the other rows right?

Comment: Yes. Maybe I should try this aproach and see wheather this works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1 - Check for the last row id.**

`SELECT * FROM $incentives_table WHERE user_id = %s AND credited = FALSE`

You can get the last row in the array and get the column row_id.

And then you can update with the where

`WHERE user_id = %s AND credited = FALSE AND row_id <= {last row id}`

**Method 2 - temp column.**

First you need to create another column in the table for this lets call it for example 'temp_user_update`.

Now when you want to get the data and then update you need first to create variable to use in your code and save it in this column.

`$temp_user_update = $sponser->ID.time();`

`UPDATE table set temp_user_update='{$temp_user_update}' WHERE user_id = %s AND credited = FALSE`

After this step you can select and update with the `WHERE temp_user_update='{$temp_user_update}'`